# Unexpected behavior of setattr() inside Metaclass __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Here is a basic `Metaclass` intending to provide a custom `__init__`:

```
class D(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attributes):
        super(D, cls).__init__(name, bases, attributes)
        for hook in R.registered_hooks:
            setattr(cls, hook.__qualname__, hook)
```

The for loop iterates over a list of functions, calling `setattr(cls, hook.__qualname__, hook)` for each of it.

Here is a Class that use the above Metaclass:

```
class E(metaclass=D):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**The weird thing:**

```
E().__dict__   prints {}
```

**But when I call**

```
`E.__dict__   prints {'f1': <function f1 at 0x001>, 'f2': <function f2 at 0x002>}`
```

I was expecting to add those function as attributes to the **instance attributes**, since the `__init__` provides a custom initialization for a Class but it seems like the attributes were added to **Class attributes**.

What is the cause of this and how can I add attributes to the instance, in this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are added as instance attributes. The instance, though, is the *class*, as an instance of the metaclass. You aren't defining a `__init__` method for `E`; you are defining the method that `type` uses to initialize `E` itself.

If you just want attributes added to the instance of `E`, you're working at the wrong level; you should define a mixin and use multiple inheritance for that.

Answer (score 2):

For `__init__` to be called on the instantiation of an object `obj`, you need to have defined `type(obj).__init__`. By using a metaclass, you defined `type(type(obj)).__init__`. You are working at the wrong level.

In this case, you only need inheritance, not a metaclass.

```
class D():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print('D.__init__ was called')

class E(D):
    pass

e = E() # prints: D.__init__ was called
```

Note that you will still find that `e.__dict__` is empty.

```
print(e.__dict__) # {}
```

This is because you instances have no attributes, methods are stored and looked up in the class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a metaclass, that means you're changing the definition of a class, which indirectly affects the attributes of instances of that class.  Assuming you actually want to do this:

You're creating a custom `__init__` method.  As with normal instantiation, `__init__` is called on an object that has been already created.  Generally when you're doing something meaningful with metaclasses, you'll want to add to the class's dict before instantiation, which is done in the `__new__` method to avoid issues that may come up in subclassing.  It should look something like this:

```
class D(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for hook in R.registered_hooks:
            dct[hook.__qualname__] = hook
        return super(D, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

This will not modify the `__dict__` of instances of that class, but attribute resolution for instances also looks for class attributes.  So if you add `foo` as an attribute for `E` in the metaclass, `E().foo` will return the expected value even though it's not visible in `E().__dict__`.